# Async logging in Django

Tags: python, django

I have created a simple weather webapp in Django using API. Logging is enabled and are written into files in Windows. I want logging to be asynchronous that is at the end of execution. How can we do async logging in Django?

Comment: What does `at the end of execution` mean? Give an example.

Comment: At the end of execution of api call

Comment: that is after rendering view to the user write log into the logfile. Currently it is writing log normally as logging works

Comment: If you want to write log after the response has been created, use middleware.

Comment: how to use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can only create async views in Django.
There is Python Logstash package which has Async way of logging, but it stores logs in a database in a remote instance.
(Alternative of which is to store logs in SQLLite3 db). File logging option is not present in it.

Moreover, async is newbie in Django and still many complexities present unresolved in it. It might cause memory overhead which
can degrade performance. Please find some links below for reference.

https://pypi.org/project/python-logstash/
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#:~:text=New%20in%20Django%203.0.,have%20efficient%20long%2Drunning%20requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#:%7E:text=New%20in%20Django%203.0.,have%20efficient%20long%2Drunning%20requests).
https://deepsource.io/blog/django-async-support/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `logging` module from python standard library

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Set file as output
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
# Formatter template
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
# add a formatter to handler
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# add a handler to logger
logger.addHandler(handler)

# your messages will be added to the file
logger.error("it's error message")
logger.info("it's info message")
logger.warning("it's warning message")
```

Official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

I hope I helped you!)

Comment: This code will write logs to a file, working like as a `print` function

Comment: yes, it will simply write logs to a file which I have already done. But I want logs written to the file at the end that is after rendering view defined in views.py file.

Comment: do you want the entire django stream to be written to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to start the django project like this. Cons: nothing will be output to the console, but it will work faster than in middleware

```
nohup python manage.py runserver > file.log
```